# xcode 12 can not install the arm64e architecture app to my iphone xs max

Tags: ios, xcode12

I builded an arm64e architecture app with xcode 12. When I wanted to install this app on my iphone xs max, it prompted:

`testApp's architectures (arm64e) include none that xxxx's iPhone can execute (arm64v8, arm64, armv8)`

Is the arm64e architecture no longer supported?